# Android get Background color on draw

Tags: android, canvas, background, draw

I'm trying to change the background color when I drawing the canvas of a CardView element. So I trying to get the background color on onDraw event, but I'm not getting.

How I get the background color on CardView onDaw event?

```
public class MyCardView extends CardView {
    public MyCardView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int bgColor = ???some method???;
        if(bgColor == 0) {
            setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Tips**: Avoiding Allocations in `onDraw()`

```
public class MyCardView extends CardView {
    private Drawable background;
    private int color = Color.RED;

    public MyCardView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        background = ((View) this.getParent()).getBackground();
        if (background instanceof ColorDrawable) {
            color = ((ColorDrawable) background).getColor();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        setBackgroundColor(color);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```